# Add class to list item based on final URL path segment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

all! Noob alert. I'm trying to add the class "active" to list items in the nav when the a's href value contains the current page's ending.

For instance, if I'm on "http://www.website.com/about/overview/" I'd want the li that contains an a with href of "/overview/" to have the class active.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.website.com/about/overview/">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.website.com/about/staff/">Staff</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.website.com/about/membership/">Membership</a></li>
</ul>
```

The script below works if I change "lastSegment" to "/overview" but I need the script to be dynamic and grab the current url's end.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function () {


    $("ul > li a[href*='lastSegment']").closest('li').addClass('active');

});

</script>
```

I think I can grab the current url's end like this

```
var url = 'window.location.href';
var lastSegment = url.split('/').pop();
```

but I apparently don't know how to use that "lastSegment" variable in the first script. Any ideas?

Comment: `$("ul > li a[href$='" + lastSegment + "']")`

Comment: @NoLifeKing Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

If you change the selector to `$("ul > li a[href$='" + lastSegment + "']")` that part would work.

But you also have to change

`var url = 'window.location.href';`

to

`var url = window.location.href;`

Comment: This, and I think perhaps there should be a quick check for the value of lastSegment as well, since technically splitting by "/" would leave an empty string after the final slash.

Comment: Yeah. Which will make all directory-links useless and marked as active. He'll have to add some checks to get the non-empty parts. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still no go, unfortunately. My code as of now is as follows:

`<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function () {

        var url = window.location.href;
        var lastSegment = url.split('/').pop();

        $("ul > li a[href*=" + lastSegment + "]").closest('li').addClass('active');
        
    });

</script>`

Does that look like is should be correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = 'window.location.href';
```

this is string and you always will get "window.location.href" in this line

```
var lastSegment = url.split('/').pop();
```

that is not correct, you need get current path

```
 var url = window.location.href;
```

and you need add this variable to selector

```
$("ul > li a[href*='lastSegment']").closest('li').addClass('active');
```

you can do it like this

```
$("ul > li a[href*=" + lastSegment + "]").closest('li').addClass('active');
```